# König-Wittstock norm on Banach space

Tags: banach-spaces, norms

Let $(E,\Vert.\Vert)$ be a real Banach space and $\ell\ne 0$
an *non-continuous* linear form on $E$. 
Let $a\in E$ be such that $\ell(a)=1$.
König-Wittstock [Non-equivalent complete norms 
and would-be continuous linear functionals, 
*Expositiones Mathematicae*, 10 (1992), 285--288] 
define a new norm on $E$ by
$$
\left\vert\mkern -1.5mu\Vert\right.
x
\left\vert\mkern -1.5mu\Vert\right.
=\vert\ell(x)\vert + \inf_{t\in \mathbb R} \Vert x-ta\Vert.
$$
I don't know how to prove that $(E,\left\vert\mkern -1.5mu\Vert\right.{.}\left\vert\mkern -1.5mu\Vert\right.)$
is also a Banach space.

Comment: Your space is isometric (by the map $x \in E \mapsto (\ell(x), x+\mathbf R a)$) to the $\ell_1$-direct sum of the Banach spaces $\mathbf R$ and $E/\mathbf R a$.